# Printing Results as Vertical List

Tags: python-3.x

Student learning Python3 here.

I have an assignment where I am told to write something for this:[image]

My current code that I have is:

```
from read_lines import read_lines

storedstrings = read_lines()
print(storedstrings)

ci = 0
contin = True
while contin:
        if ci > len(storedstrings):
                contin = False
        else:
                storedstrings = storedstrings[0]
                ci = ci + 1
                print(ci, storedstrings)
```

But when I run it, my result is:

```
[vbox]~/CSE1010/HW4$ python3 loop.py
abc
def
ghi

['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
1 abc
2 a
[vbox]~/CSE1010/HW4$
```

I cannot seem to get the second or third index to come out correctly, though the first one is fine.

Would appreciate any help.

Thank you guys for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `storedstrings = storedstrings[0]`.
You're taking the first string, and assigning it to the same name. So next time `storedstrings[0]` happens, you are getting the first character of the first string. What you instead would want to do is:

```
string = storedstrings[ci]
```

Instead of using that while loop, it would be easier to use a for loop along with [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate). Then it would be as simple as:

```
for i, string in enumerate(storedstrings, start=1):
    print(i, string)
```

Output:

```
1 abc
2 def
3 ghi
```

Comment: I see. That makes sense to me now. Thank you very much. Another question here if you may please answer: When I edited my code to yours and ran the script, everything would print out fine, but then I would end up with the error "list index out of range". But when I switched my ifstatement to `if ci = len(storedstrings):`, it works as intended. Why exactly is this the case ? If I have three items in my list and I used ci (which is 3) equal to len(storedstrings), which is also 3, shouldn't it return False and end the program? Why does it keep continuing as intended?

Comment: If you replaced the while with the for loop, then you shouldn't get an index out of range error. What you actually need to do in case of your if statement is `if ci == len(storedstrings) - 1`. Note the `- 1` and I assume the single equals sign was a mistake. Remember that lists are zero-based. So of a list of 3 elements, the first index would be `0` and the last `2`. Thus why you check `ci == len(storedstrings) - 1`.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much again for your help.